# Sprite cannot be fixed in 2D in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I am running ubuntu 14.04 with Phaser (v2.3.0 "Tarabon" - Built: Thu Mar 26 2015 02:36:37).

I am trying to have two sprites where one of them (`yellowRectangle`) should be fixed and the other one (`redSquare`) moves toward the fixed sprite.

The issue is that the sprite that should be fixed still moves when the two sprites collide.

I attempted the workaround to set `yellowRectangle.physicsType = Phaser.SPRITE;`
but it does not help.

Here is the short program:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(width="100", height="100", Phaser.AUTO,'pressIt', { preload: preload, create: create, update:update });

var redSquare; var yellowRectangle;


function preload() {
    game.load.image('redSquare', '/redSquare25x25.png');
    game.load.image('yellowRectangle', '/yellowRectangle100x10.png');
}

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

    redSquare = game.add.sprite(x=game.world.centerX, y=35, 'redSquare');
    game.physics.p2.enable(redSquare);

    yellowRectangle = game.add.sprite(x=game.world.centerX, y=game.world.height - 100, 'yellowRectangle');
    //was suggested to add due to bug in Phaser, but does not fix it
    //yellowRectangle.physicsType = Phaser.SPRITE;
    game.physics.p2.enable(yellowRectangle);
    yellowRectangle.body.moves = false;
    yellowRectangle.immovable = true; 
};

function update() {
    redSquare.body.force.y = 500; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the yellow rectangle as immovable like this:

`yellowRectangle.body.immovable = true;`

You just forgot the `body` part ;)

Hope it helps!